# Replace non-alphanumeric characters in substring

Tags: regex, awk, sed, tr

I am trying to replace any non-alphanumeric characters present in the first part (before the `=` sign) of a bunch of key value pairs, by a `_`:

**Input**

```
aa:cc:dd=foo-bar|17657V70YPQOV
ee-ff/gg=barFOO
```

**Desired Output**

```
aa_cc_dd=foo-bar|17657V70YPQOV
ee_ff_gg=barFOO
```

I have tried patterns such as: `s/\([^a-zA-Z]*\)=\(.*\)/\1=\2/g` without much success. Any basic GNU/Linux tools can probably be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS='=' '{gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "_", $1)} 1' ip.txt 
aa_cc_dd=foo-bar|17657V70YPQOV
ee_ff_gg=barFOO
```

Input and output field separators are set to `=` and then `gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "_", $1)` will substitute all non-alphabet characters with `_` only for first field

With `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/^[^=]+/$&=~s|[^a-z]|_|gir/e' ip.txt 
aa_cc_dd=foo-bar|17657V70YPQOV
ee_ff_gg=barFOO
```

- `^[^=]+` non `=` characters from start of line
- `$&=~s|[^a-z]|_|gir` replace non-alphabet characters with `_` only for the matched portion
- Use `perl -i -pe` for inplace editing

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is in a file called `infile`, you could do this:

```
while IFS== read key value; do
    printf '%s=%s\n' "${key//[![:alnum:]]/_}" "${value}"
done < infile
```

with the output

```
aa_cc_dd=foo-bar|17657V70YPQOV
ee_ff_gg=barFOO
```

This sets the `IFS` variable to `=` and reads your key/value pairs line by line into a `key` and a `value` variable.

The `printf` command prints them and adds the `=` back in; `"${key//[![:alnum:]]/_}"` substitutes all non-alphanumeric characters in `key` by an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Any `Posix` compliant `awk`

```
$ cat f
aa:cc:dd=foo-bar|17657V70YPQOV
ee-ff/gg=barFOO

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"_",$1)+1' f
aa_cc_dd=foo-bar|17657V70YPQOV
ee_ff_gg=barFOO
```

**Explanation**

`BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}` Set input and Output field separator `=`

`/[^[:alnum:]]/` Match a character not present in the list, 
  `[:alnum:]`  matches a alphanumeric character `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

> `gsub(REGEXP, REPLACEMENT, TARGET)`
>        This is similar to the `sub` function, except `gsub` replaces
>        *all* of the longest, leftmost, *nonoverlapping* matching
>        substrings it can find.  The `g` in `gsub` stands for global, which means replace everywhere,The `gsub` function returns the number
>   of substitutions made

`+1` It takes care of default operation `{print $0}` whenever gsub returns `0`

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would throw a little ruby in:

```
ruby -pe '$_.sub!(/[^=]+/){|m| m.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"_")}'
```